# OpenGL SuperBible 5th Ed. Triangle blue background

Tags: opengl

Sorry to have to dig up such an old book. But I'm using the OpenGL SB 5E because my mac only supports OpenGL 3.3.

I'm currently working on the first sample program, Triangle.cpp. I have included all the necessary files, set up the correct path, and built and ran the program.

I am having an issue with the display of the program. It is supposed to display a red triangle on a blue background. I am able to see the red triangle, but the blue background displays other scattered images of my screen.

screenshot:

[image]

In all honesty I have no idea what could be causing this issue. I do however have 4 warnings that appear from the GLTools.h:

- Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'glGenVertexArrays' macro redefined
- Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'glDeleteVertexArrays' macro redefined
- Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'glBindVertexArray' macro redefined
- Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'glGenerateMipmap' macro redefined

Could these be a possible cause to the issue?

Macbook Pro 3,1 - 2.2GHz, 4GB Ram

Comment: can you show us the code you are using to clear the screen? should be something along the lines of ``glClearColor(0,0,1,1)`` (for blue) and for each frame ``glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)``.